# "Put a spanner in the works" en français

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, tropes

Est-ce que il y a une expression en français équivalent à *put a spanner in the works* ? Ça veut dire que quelqu'un a fait quelque chose qui empêche quelque autre chose ou un plan de réussir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Les bâtons dans les roues

étaient aussi ma première pensée. Il y a aussi l'expression

> Le grain de sable dans l'engrenage

qui conserve la référence a la machinerie

Comment: Très bonne réponse. Pour la seconde proposition : l'idée impliquant un contraste entre le (petit) élément perturbateur et le (grand) système, il me semble que la formule plus courante est *un grain de sable dans l'engrenage*.

Comment: Oui le grain solitaire est plus poétique. La grosse poignée probablement plus efficace!

Answer (score 6):

La première chose qui me vient à l'esprit c'est [ceci](http://www.languefrancaise.net/bob/detail.php?id=34639)

> mettre des bâtons dans les roues

Qui correspond bien à l'idée d'empêcher quelqu'un de faire quelque chose.